# how can i fix the IndexError: list index out of range when i add [0] to face_encodings?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, face-recognition

I am trying to learn face recorgnition and have tried it on both google colab and jupyter notebook and I get an IndexError: list index out of range when I code the write way of adding the index [0] but it does not give an error when I omit [0] in which case I get another error when I try to compare the faces.
here is what my error looks like

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()

```
  2 for file in os.listdir(known_dir):

  3   img = read_img(known_dir + '/' + file)
```

----> 4   img_enc = face_recognition.face_encodings(img)[0]

```
  5   known_encodings.append(img_enc)

  6   known_names.append(file.split('.')[0])
```

IndexError: list index out of range

and here is my code

```
known_dir = '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/behic_faces'
for file in os.listdir(known_dir):
    img = read_img(known_dir + '/' + file)
    img_enc = face_recognition.face_encodings(img)[0]
    known_encodings.append(img_enc)
    known_names.append(file.split('.')[0])
```

Comment: Without knowing about the library you're using, my guess is that `face_recognition.face_encodings(img)` is returning an empty list.  In effect, there are no `face_encodings` associated with the image you just read. - you could assign `face_recognition.face_encodings(img)` to a variable, which as you say, works, and then call `len()` on that variable.  I bet you get `0`. You could also call `type` on that variable to see just what it is, but I expect it's a `list`.

Comment: In Jupyter notebook, use %debug and check elements in your lst.

Comment: thank you, i have fixed it. however when i try to compare faces I get a
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'... please i would appreciate your suggestions